# File chooser dialog from a batch file and select the path of file alone and filename alone

Tags: file, batch-file, dialog

I need a dialog box within a batch file that can select the path of a file and the filename as well.

For example:

http://pastebin.com/ag8avdWw

However this code needs the .NET framework - is there a solution without needing a framework like .NET?

Comment: Windows Explorer **is** the file chooser for .bat files.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a batch file that will allow you to select a file, and get the `path` and `filename` and uses Powershell to get the selector.

**Edit:** Your `powershell execution policy` has to be changed to allow you to run scripts written by you before the file selector box will appear when you launch the batch file.

Change `"c:\"` if you want to start in another drive or folder.

```
@echo off
:loop
set "tempfile=%temp%\file-%random%"
if exist "%tempfile%" goto :loop

call :getfile "c:\"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell "%tempfile%.ps1" ') do (
   set "filepath=%%~dpa"
   set "filename=%%~nxa"
)
del "%tempfile%.ps1"

echo  path is: "%filepath%"
echo  file is: "%filename%"
pause
goto :EOF

:getfile
(
echo $initialDirectory = "%~1"
echo [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName^("System.windows.forms"^) ^| Out-Null
echo $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
echo $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
echo $OpenFileDialog.filter = "All files (*.*)| *.*"
echo $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog^(^) ^| Out-Null
echo $OpenFileDialog.filename
) > "%tempfile%.ps1"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: can you add the dialog to select the filename and path from the file you selected from dialog ?

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: i want when i start the batch file show dialog and i will select the file after that the dialog will close and will show to me the filename of the file i select (alone) and the path of the file (alone)

Comment: Doesn't the code do that?  What happens on your computer?

Comment: your code does not have dialog i want to edit your code to get the information from the dialog (the path alone and the filename alone)

Comment: when i run this code i see cmd for 5 sec (supposed i see the dialog) and it will type in cmd                                               path is " "                                                        file is " "

Comment: Did you change the code?  There is a pause command that allows you to see what it prints to the console. Try copy and pasting the code again.  Also - open a CMD window - and drop the bat file in the window.  Let me know if there are any error messages.

Comment: when i write the code there is dialog but when i start the code i dont see the dialog i see the cmd for 5 sec and it will stop to show in cmd (((path is " " and in the next line file is " ")))

Comment: Do you see any error messages?  Do you see a file selection menu?

Comment: I see what the problem is.  Your `powershell execution policy` hasn't been changed from the default state of `disallowing all scripts`.  I'm not sure if you are able to change that, if you are in a corporate environment, or if you want to change that.

Comment: no i am not do anything with my powershell(((can you give me another code)))